# How to remove space between two inline-blocks using Slim?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

In vanilla HTML I used comments like this:

`<div id="one"></div><!--`

`--><div id="two"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not possible in Slim. This would be possible in Haml, using `<` for the parent element.

Some people use inline html for such cases:

[Slim templates - removing whitespaces around the block tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737779/slim-templates-removing-whitespaces-around-the-block-tag)